# AppleScripts: display notification is too fast to display properly

Tags: applescript

I don't recall if this changed recently (I'm on 10.13), but when I call display notification in a fast loop, the notification changes to "N new notifications". Totally unhelpful for most of my scripts.

I've tried sporadically calling the notification with

```
if notificationCount / someDenom = (notificationCount / someDenom) as integer then display notification "etc."
```

which works if how long a loop will take is a known quantity. But half the time, I'm calling the scripts sometimes on a local drive, other times over a network, and the results are unpredictable. Either I don't get frequent enough notifications, or it collapses into the too many display sometimes.

Thinking it's entirely possible that this is baked into macOS and there's nothing I can do except the above, but thought someone might have a bright idea.

[Edited to add: just had one myself, a subroutine which notes the datestamp and elapsed time since the last call, then only calls the notification if N seconds have passed. I'll give that a try.]

[Edited again: well, that technically works, but it adds 0.68 seconds to every notification, which is a pretty high cost in a tight loop.]

Comment: What are you using notifications for? A progress monitor? In that case, you could use the AppleScript `progress` interfaces. They aren't _great_, but they can get the job done. If you use that, when your script is running you can click the spinning gear in the menu bar to see the "progress description" and whatnot

Comment: Ah. That's new to me, and yes, it would be useful in a bunch of places. But it's suboptimal for scripts launched from the Script Menu, which is where a fair number of my scripts live.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but it works for scripts:

```
delay 1
display notification "uno momento..."
delay 1
display notification "it works!"
```

Meaning, figure out a way to add a delay between notifications if they're not appearing / play with the delay time until it works for your purposes. I found using 1 sec is OK since users will read at that speed, and it allows the OS time to catch up and ensures all notifications are listed in order AND all of them show up / are displayed to user.

I found I also have to include a delay *prior* to the first notification, if sending notifications in a group...again ensuring first notify displays properly.

Comment: Hi @bbiasi - question: what's the difference between you're and you are?  Why would you change my English?  "you're" is correct - simply curious.  :)

Comment: None. I do not remember completely, but I think it was 1 character to edit your code, put it with the fences. Sorry, my intention was just to improve the aesthetics of the code.

Comment: ok thank you - I haven't added any comments to stackoverflow yet so I thought for some strange reason we couldn't use an apostrophe.  haha   thanks for showing me the code snippets / now I get it.